LookerStudio Blend not providing same amount of data as direct connection
I am testing the difference between data received by using blends vs using a direct connector. I have a direct connection to a Google BigQuery table. And I also have a blend to that same connection to the BigQuery table. There is just that connection in the blend, not another table, no join, no anything.
However, my direct connection returns 12,780 rows, while The blend returns only 4,725 rows. The configuration is the same. I can also see which data is missing and I can not find any pattern. The missing data is not only from the end or just the beginning of the query, it's dispersed.
Does anyone have any idea on why this could happen?
Does the blend maybe reduce the result for any reason?
Could it be maybe because I am not supposed to use a blend if I have only one table in it (so not joining any 2 or multiple tables)?
Thank you
